# join two tables with selected condition php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using three tables in the database and query that I should combine. The tables look like:

Table message:

```
message_id   | msg_id |   conv_id   | text    | user_id
--------------------------------------------------------------
    1        |    1   |     1       |  hi     |   12
    2        |    1   |     1       |  Thanks |   14
    3        |    2   |     4       |  helo   |   21
```

Table conversation:

```
   conv_id      |   msg_id |   conv_id   | subject  | user_id  | text 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1        |   1      |     1       |  sub1    |    12    |  Hi to all
       2        |   1      |     1       |  sub1    |    14    |  Hi to all
       3        |   2      |     4       |  sub3    |    21    |  reply2
```

the both table having msg_id is the common ,

**my expected result is,**

from conversation table group by msg_id ,

from messsage table message.msg_id=conversation.msg_id

```
   conv_id      |   msg_id   |   conv_id   | subject  | text
-----------------------------------------------------------------
       1        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    | Hi to all
       1        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    | hi
       2        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    | thanks
       3        |   2        |     4       |  sub3    | helo
```

my query is

```
SELECT *
FROM mailbox_message m1
LEFT JOIN mailbox_conversation m2 ON m1.conversation_id=m2.conversation_id
WHERE m2.msg_id='1'
ORDER BY m1.created DESC
```

my query returns the following

```
   conv_id      |   msg_id   |   conv_id   | subject  | text
-----------------------------------------------------------------
       1        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    |   Hi to all
       2        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    |   Hi to all    
       1        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    |    hi
       2        |   1        |     1       |  sub1    |    thanks
       3        |   2        |     4       |  sub3    |    helo
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the locig behind your expected result?

Comment: the conversation table stores the initiating message , i mean if we send to mail 3 members it will store 3 times , message table is used to store the replies. i need to retrieve from conversation table only one row instead of 3 and all the message in message table by using msg_id

Comment: so the same user is responding to their initiating message? its the same user id for the rows?

Comment: simply i want to group by msg_id in conversation table and get the related msg_id records in message table

Comment: @DhanushBala your conversation table has 2 columns with same name i.e `conv_id` its not possible to have same name for 2 columns please provide correct table definitions

Comment: and include `created` as it is referenced in your query